# Binary API documentation via swagger

Tags: api, http, binary, swagger, documentation

I'm building an API that's able to upload multiple files at once. I need to document it through swagger, but I have no experience with it at all.
My schema for the API is as follows:

The http request body is an octet-stream that looks like this. The first 4 bytes represents the number of packages, let the number of packages be n. The next 4*n bytes represents the sizes of the packages, where the first 4 bytes is the size of the first package, the next 4 is the size of the second package, etc. The end of the request simply consists of the packages.

An example would be: The packages `\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF` and `\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xCA\xFE\xBE\xEF`, would compose the request:

```
\x00\x00\x00\x02||\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x08||\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xCA\xFE\xBE\xEF
```

I've tried documenting this in swagger like this:

```
 Batch:
      type: object
      properties:
        header:
          description: The number of packages represented in binary (big endian).
          type: string
          format: binary
          maxLength: 8
          minLength: 8
          example: \x00\x00\x00\x02
        subheader:
          description: The size of each package, where the size of the first package is represented by the first 4 bytes, the second by the next 4 bytes, etc (big endnian).
          type: string
          format: binary
          maxLength: 4294967295
          minLength: 0
          example: \x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04
        data:
          description: The data block for encryption/decryption
          type: string
          format: binary
          maxLength: 18446744073709551616
          minLength: 0
          example: \xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF
```

But it shows the request body as a json object (due to `type: object`).
Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octet-stream request body is defined as a single binary string. There's no way to define the contents/format of specific fragments of the octet-stream. `minLength` and `maxLength` can be used to limit the size of the entire stream.

Also note that this is OpenAPI 3.0. OpenAPI 2.0 does not support `application/octet-stream` payloads (it only supports `multipart/form-data`).

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2

paths:
  /something:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/octet-stream:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: binary
              maxLength: 12345
```

Comment: I'm using OpenAPI 3.0, so this will do. It's a shame that this feature is missing. Thank you for the quick response! :)

Comment: Feel free to submit enhancement requests in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues

Comment: Where do you read that openapi does not support application/octet-stream?
Any content-type be specified in a spec.
There is a working example of this here:
- spec https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/python/petstore-with-fake-endpoints-models-for-testing-with-http-signature.yaml#L1266

Comment: @spacether by "OpenAPI 2.0 does not support application/octet-stream payloads" I meant that OpenAPI 2.0 does not have a way to define binary file uploads with `Content: application/octet-stream` (or `applization/zip`, or whatever) and *request body containing raw binary file data* - i.e. analog of `curl --upload-file archive.zip http://example.com/upload`. OAS2 only supports file uploads using `multipart/form-data`. Arbitrary file uploads (e.g. PUT/POST octet-stream) are supported in OpenAPI 3.x only.